# Setup Encryption Key in Neptune Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-neptune, amazon-kms, graph-notebook

I am trying to bulk load RDF data to Neptune Database and visualize the graph using Notebook. For this, I have created a Neptune Database with Encryption key (KMS customer managed key) added into it. Also, I have created a Neptune Notebook (from AWS console > Neptune > create notebook) associated with the created Database, but I didn't find any option to add the Encryption key in Neptune notebook. I require my Neptune Notebook to be Encrypted by encryption key.

May I know how can I create a Neptune notebook with Encryption key (KMS customer managed key) associated with the Neptune cluster to load and visualize data?

Comment: Just to clarify is the requirement to be able to specify a customer managed KMS key when the Jupyter notebook instance is created so that files on the instance are encrypted using that key rather than the default AWS key?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence Yes, the reason to specify a customer managed KMS key is to encrypt the files on the instance rather than using the default AWS key

Comment: In the near term, perhaps creating a SageMaker instance yourself using the keys etc. you require and then copying over the lifecycle script from the one Neptune deployed might be an option?